# Php mkdir( ) exception handling

Tags: php, exception, mkdir

mkdir() is working correctly this question is more about catching an error. Instead of printing this when the directory exists I would just like to have it write to a message to me in a custom log. How do I create this exception.

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would just like to have it write to a message to me in a custom log.

the solution is very easy. PHP already have everything for you:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('error_log','/path/to/custom.log');
```

or same settings in the php.ini or .htaccess
I think it would be better than write each possible error manually

If you don't want this error to be logged (as it may be not error but part of application logic), you can check folder existence first

```
if (!file_exists($folder)) mkdir($folder);
else {/*take some appropriate action*/}
```

Comment: You caught on to what I was trying to do. I can avoid the situation entirely by using file_exsists(). I used your answer to solve my problem. Thank You.

Comment: I have to say that both answers where good and nikc's answers is definitely more technically correct especially about handling the error. I imagine Shrapnel knew that I was just screwing up and wouldn't need to handle any errors if I just did things right =)

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the error message from displaying either by suppressing error messages globally (in config or runtime) with the [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) setting, or case by case by prefixing the function call with an `@`-character. (E.g. `@mkdir('...')`).

You can then check with [`error_get_last`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)  when `mkdir` returns `false`.

For error logging global rules apply. You can log errors manually with [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

For further reading, see the manual section on [Error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php).

Edit:

As suggested in the comments, a custom error handler is also a possible, arguably more robust (depending on your implementation) but certainly more elegant, solution.

```
function err_handler($errno, $errstr) {
    // Ignore or log error here
}

set_error_handler('err_handler');
```

This way, the error message will not display, unless you explicitly echo it. Note, though, when using a custom error handler `error_get_last` will return `NULL`.

Comment: I should point out it's good practice as well as constructive to comment when downvoting. (Not to mention polite.)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but maybe it's because someone saw the @-operator and considers it bad practise? (I do, myself, I'd suggest a custom error handler instead, with `set_error_handler`, but I think this answer is still *very* valid and helpful.)

Comment: Indeed, a custom error handler would be a more elegant solution. But in cases as described I think the @-operator is an acceptable solution, since it looks to me as a one off situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite any system call function with a class like this:

`file: system.php`

```
namespace abc;

class System {

    const CAN_NOT_MAKE_DIRECTORY = 1;

    static public function makeDirectory($path) {
        $cmd = "mkdir " . $path;
        $output = \shell_exec($cmd . " 2>&1"); // system call
        if ($output != "") {
            throw new \Exception($output, System::CAN_NOT_MAKE_DIRECTORY);
        }
        return(\TRUE);
    }

}
```

Then you can call the method and intercept the exception:

`file: index.php`

```
namespace abc;
require 'system.php';

try {
    System::makeDirectory($directoryName);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), System::CAN_NOT_MAKE_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Now you can treat all the system errors with the `try {...} catch(...) {...} finally {...}` normally.

Comment: This is a slow way to do it. The `mkdir()` function does not launch a whole other program.

Comment: I have never benchmarking this method and I suspect you probably right about the timing, but this post is not about the productivity. This post is about how to make try-catch-finally friendly system calls.

Comment: There are other ways to make it try-catch friendly than forking a new process for a simple system call. It's silly.